# Php capitalise word after bracket

Tags: php

I am trying to capitalise every word in a php string but the function isn't detecting a word that is being immediately followed by a bracket. How can I make it so that a word directly after a bracket is capitalised?

Example: amharic (ethiopian)   .... Amharic (Ethiopian)

(currently using ucwords(), PHP displays Amharic (ethiopian) )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21626) which requires there to be whitespace between open-parenthesis and the first letter.  Here's a workaround:

```
$var = "amharic (ethiopian)";

echo str_replace('( ', '(', ucwords(str_replace('(', '( ', $var)));
```

**Result**

```
Amharic (Ethiopian)
```

[See the demo](http://codepad.org/dF4gmNAL)

Comment: using it in drupal: Warning: strtr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in format_string()

Comment: @Francesco This question is tagged [tag:PHP]

Comment: For anyone else looking at this voted correct answer, please see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77978410/2036922

`ucwords` accepts a 2nd parameter where you can pass which characters should be considered "beginning of word".  No need for regex or any other fancy tricks..

Answer (score 8):

Try this,i tried it ,

```
$text= "amharic (ethiopian)";
echo mb_convert_case($text, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

> **output**  : Amharic (Ethiopian)

Note:It looks like the mbstring function on PHP is to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Below function use to covert word with Bracket into Capitalize after Bracket

```
    function ucWordWithBracket($edit){
        $new_word = str_replace("(","( ",$edit);
        $temp = ucwords($new_word);
        $new_word = str_replace("( ","(",$temp);
        return $new_word;
    }
```

ucWordWithBracket(amharic (ethiopian))

Output of funcation is "Amharic (Ethiopian)";

Answer (score 1):

`ucwords` accepts a 2nd parameter for custom separator, as described in the documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php).

Try something like:
`ucwords($string,"( \t\r\n\f\v")` (note the `(` at the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve it with preg_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and a regular expression like `/[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*/` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that php is going to capitalise the first character after the space and because the bracket is just a character after the space so it is considered as the first character in the word must be capitalise and other characters folow it are considered as characters of this world

So to work around this i think you must make space between bracket and characters so php can detect the bracket as a single character and not a begin character of a word :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else needing to title case around other characters including dashes, brackets and parentheses. You can use regex with preg_replace_callback to capture a word that is split with a dash or begins with a character not in the alphabet.

```
/** Capitalize first letter if string is only one word **/
    $STR = ucwords(strtolower($STR));

/** Correct Title Case for words with non-alphabet charcters ex. Screw-Washer **/
    $STR = preg_replace_callback('/([A-Z]*)([^A-Z]+)([A-Z]+)/i', 
        function ($matches) {
            $return = ucwords(strtolower($matches[1])).$matches[2].ucwords(strtolower($matches[3]));
            return $return;
        }, $STR);
```